# MacPorts set PHP82 as php

Tags: macports, php

I am having a problem with correctly installing PHP using MacPorts.
I installed PHP8.2 using `sudo port install php`.

But I can't run PHP with `php`. I have to specify the exact version `php82`. I didn't see a command for setting this, like with python.

```
sudo port select --set python3 python311
sudo port select --set python python311
```

I there a port command similar for PHP?

Comment: I don't use php but looking at port info for php and php82 I think you want to install php82 and the port select. I think the php port is a base for all versions and not really one to be used - I would guess it is that way for historic reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `php` (or anything) to participate in MacPorts' alternatives selection method, you have to install the *-select port that goes along with whatever the tool is.

For `php`, that is [php-select](https://ports.macports.org/port/php_select/) .

Comment: I don't how I missed that. I just assumed. Thanks.